# GradientBoostingClassifier - How to get the node index of each tree

Tags: scikit-learn

Can the node index of each tree in sklearn GradientBoostingClassifier be retrieved?

I know that for sklearn RandomForestClassifier the apply method can be used for that, but how it can be done with GradientBoostingClassifier?

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method of the `tree_` object of each `DecisionTreeRegressor`.